# Recursive Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I'm having trouble getting my head around a problem on recursive nested lists. The problem; need to define a procedure to access a nested list to an arbitrary depth. It would take an nested list and an index, and return the part of the list at that index. From this given function, recursively find the value at the given index.

For example

Well here is a better visual representation. To select the element 9 out of it, we need to do something like
nested[3][1]

```
    nested = \
    [[[1, 2],
      3],
     [4,
      [5, 6]],
     7,
     [8, 9, 10]]
```

```
recursive_func(nested_list, [3,1]) #recursive function definition, the second argument is the index at which the data needs to be retrieved.  
>>> 9 #so given the function an index of [3,1] would return 9
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be grateful

Comment: Can you clarify what the function should do? Also, if this is homework, please tag it so

Comment: @Ben: As @Eli said you need to specify the problem better. One way to do this is by providing additional examples. It is very unclear how the input in your current example translates into the output you show.

Comment: I don't get your example. What is the meaning of [3,1]? List with index 3 and element with index 1? How can the value for this query be be 1? Should the request be [2,0]?

Comment: Does [3,1] indicate that you want the first element at depth 3?

Comment: @veredesmarald Yes that's correct

Comment: @Ben E: The result line is still wrong in your example, it should be 9 not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do you, but I'm still not 100% sure what you are looking for...

```
>>> def findItem(nested, pos):
    if pos[0] == 1:
        return nested[pos[1]-1]
    else:
        nextLevelDown = []
        for item in nested:
            if type(item) == type([]):
                nextLevelDown = nextLevelDown + item
        return findItem(nextLevelDown, [pos[0]-1, pos[1]])

>>> findItem([[[1, 2], 3], 4], [3, 1])
1
>>> findItem([[[1, 2], [3]], 4], [3, 3])
3
>>> findItem([[[1, 2], [3]], 4], [2, 2])
[3]
```

UPDATE: So after much back and forth, I finally understand the question, and it is much simpler than it originally seemed, all you need is:

```
>>> def recursiveRef(nested, idxList):
    if len(idxList) > 1:
        return recursiveRef(nested[idxList[0]], idxList[1:])
    return nested[idxList[0]] 

>>> recursiveRef([[[1, 2], 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9, 10]], [3, 1])
9
```

Comment: @veredesmarald i just tried it findItem([[[1, 2], 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9, 10]], [3, 1]) >>> 1 should be 9. Thanks for the attempt i'm starting to understand how to attempt these kinds of problems now

Comment: @Ben E: How did you arrive at 9? The first element at depth 3 in that list is indeed 1. 9 isn't even 3 levels deep, only 2... I would have expect the index of 9 to be [2, 6], or possibly [2, 4] if you only count the integers at a certain depth and not the lists...

Comment: is kinda hard to explain. so 3 deep is [8, 9, 10] and 1 deep into [8, 9, 10] = 9

Comment: @Ben E: Sorry, but I have great difficulty understanding your co-ordinate system... How is [8,9,10] 3 levels deep when it is nested directly inside the outermost list? Unless you can more fully explain the meaning of the two values in the position I don't think I can help any further...

Comment: 'nested = \
    [[[1, 2],
      3],
     [4,
      [5, 6]],
     7,
     [8, 9, 10]]'
Well here is a better visual representation. To select the element 9 out of it, we need to do something like
nested[3][1]

Comment: <pre> tags don't work in comments, so that didnt help much. :( Try adding the additional example to the original question.

Comment: @veredesmarald i updated that post please check, also thanks for the help so far much appreciated. I find that my HW questions are worded badly so it makes it harder to understand.

Comment: @Ben E: See my updated answer. In the future you should make sure your examples are correct the first time around to save many headaches! :)

Comment: @verdesmarald Sorry about that kinda had a big day and didn't proof read. Thanks for your help in understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want simply turn nested list into non-nested? And then check the index? If so, then you can try something like this (I don't have python at the moment, so treat it like a pseudocode):

```
def unwrap_list(list, result):
   if type(list) == type([]):
      for value in list:
         unwrap_list(value, result)
   else:
      result.append(list)
```

Make sure, to define variable `unwrapped = []` before calling this function and use `unwrap_list(list, unwrapped)`. The result will be stored in variable `unwrapped`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this generates the answer the OP asks for ? (namely, `1` for the given input)

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, then first you call `unwrap_list(nested_list, result)` and then just check `result[index]`. I don't really understand the second argument in `recursive_func(nested_list, [3,1])` (I assumed, that it is a mistake and it should be `recursive_func(nested_list, 1)`) but what I wrote is a hint for doing recursion in this case.

Comment: The second argument is a index into the nested list. Its the position of were the data i want to retrieve. so at position [3,1] would return the integer of 1

Comment: @Ben E: why is `[3, 1]` a position? it's a list. can you explain what it means?

Comment: Well position as in being an index into the list. So for example n = [1,2,3] to access 2 it would use the index 1 (n[1])